# ZoneMinder: improve motion detection?

Tags: linux, camera, motion-detection, zoneminder

I started to use [ZoneMinder](http://www.zoneminder.com/) but I'm getting lots of false alarms.

False alarm example: because of occasional noise in the image, it triggers alarm although nothing has really changed.

Delayed alarm example: sometimes the alarm is triggered, but the person that did it has almost left the camera's sight.

Do you know how can I improve this?

I already tried all presets, but none of them seem to work correctly.